# What's the meaning of 伐 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

The sentence is : 好徒儿你就饶了为师伐。
The general meaning, is as i understand in a very literally translation “good apprentice ,you just forgive the teacher / 伐 ”
The original translation (the one that comes with the sentence) is "Please spare me , apprentice"
i know there is a "illeism" , the speaker is referring to himself as 师 ，in 3rd person to his 徒儿.

But i don't have a little idea what the function of 伐 is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, 伐 is a modal particle similar to 吧. Here it expresses the imperative mood, so the original translation doesn't include it at all.

As a native speaker, I think it comes from [Wu Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_Chinese), because in my experience I usually hear people from Shanghai (or neighbour provinces/cities) saying it. As another example they may say 先吃饭好伐？(Let's have meal first, alright?)

Answer (score 1):

In modern mandarin, it's a mistake. No body would say like this.

伐 only should occur in "讨伐", "伐木", means use some tool/weapon to destruct something.

in your sentence, 伐 is only a 拟声词/代词, similar with 格了半颗马路牙子, 胳了半 means 手肘, only a 拟声词.

就饶了为师伐  =  就饶了为师吧.

As far as I know, 伐 is from the Shanghai language.

Answer (score 0):

好徒儿你就饶了为师伐。
good disciple you then leave alone me（为师） fa
Dear student, please stop disturbing me yeah.